# SSRS Printing Multiple of the Same Invoice

Tags: sql, forms, printing, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I am developing a "Proof of Delivery" form for my organization using SSRS Report Builder on a SQL Server 2008R2 Database. I am having difficulties printing multiple copies of the same form with a different watermark (Driver Copy/Customer Copy). All of the same info is on both forms. I read about using page breaks and copying the original tablix so there are two tables on one development page. This works for creating those forms. However, when I print, all of the "Driver Copy" form print first then "Customer Copy".

The Following is an example of the print order:

```
Invoice Number 12345 Driver Copy
Invoice Number 67890 Driver Copy
Invoice Number 12345 Customer Copy
Invoice Number 67890 Customer Copy
```

I would like to print like the following:

```
Invoice Number 12345 Driver Copy
Invoice Number 12345 Customer Copy
Invoice Number 67890 Driver Copy
Invoice Number 67890 Customer Copy
```

Collating isn't the huge of an ordeal until we have 200+ forms to print. Is there any way within Report Builder 3.0 or BIDS for me to achieve this?

BTW, the data source can not be manipulated. However, if there is a way to do this within the query builder, I'm open to it.

Answer (score 1):

Put a "List" Data region on the design surface from the toolbox (BIDS) or insert it from the ribbon (in RS Builder), and then place the two tables on it. Set the grouping for the list item (which is actually a tablix with one cell and a rectangle) to the "invoice number". This will group visually your forms.

You can additionally set a sorting to get back the results in the correct order (driver -> customer copy)

If you want to have page breaks between each instance of the grouping, you can edit the page breaks of your "List" data region.